# Java Converter NumberFormatException error

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with my Java program? I'm currently making a currency converter and i need to make an option where the user can enter a British pound amount and click convert for it to convert, then have the option to enter their own exchange rate into the calculation and when convert is clicked then it will use the users inputted exchange rate instead of the one that i have set. Here is the code i have so far to convert GBP to USD, the program works when i input an amount and also input an exchange rate myself, however the option to leave the input exchange rate box empty and use the constant exchange rate set brings an error when converted:

```
public class cConverter extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    double GBPtoUSD = 1.288;

    //this is the constant exchange rate for GBP to USD.
    private void BtnConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
        double ConvertFromGBP = Double.parseDouble(InputFrom.getText());
        double GetExchange = Double.parseDouble(ExchangeRateFrom.getText());

        /* Input from is where the user inputs the GBP amount they want converted. 
           ExchangeRateFrom is the optional exchange rate box where the user inputs an 
           updated exchange rate if the constant one is out of date. */

        if (CurrencyTop.getSelectedItem().equals("USD")) {
            String cGBPtoUSD = String.format("%.2f", ConvertFromGBP * GBPtoUSD);
            ConvertedFrom.setText(cGBPtoUSD);
        }
        else if (CurrencyTop.getSelectedItem().equals("USD")) {
            String uGBPtoUSD = String.format("%.2f", GetExchange * ConvertFromGBP);
            ConvertedFrom.setText(uGBPtoUSD);
        }

        /* CurrencyTop is a combo box containing the currencies to convert to. 
           ConvertedFrom is the calculation output label. */
```

Error exception when converting without inputting an exchange rate (should be using the GBPtoUSD double when nothing is inputted to this box):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

Heres a GIF of the error in action:
https://gyazo.com/af8d681e8f5cf190b2ed2c61b53efa8e

Here is an updated version based upon some feedback however I'm still getting the same error:
https://gist.github.com/liamrice18/2aae2ec72bdfa34ea308519d131c47b8

Thank you

Comment: what else do you expect `double GetExchange = Double.parseDouble(ExchangeRateFrom.getText());` to do?

Comment: Why is your class name starting with a lower case? Its a bad coding practice.

Comment: How does the computer know that "should be using the GBPtoUSD double when nothing is inputted to this box"? I cannot see any code implementing this - you must write the code to check if the input is empty and hen use GBPtoUSD (instead of converting to double in that case).

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thats what im asking for help with, I do not know how to check if it is empty...

Comment: sorry, kind of confused since you asked about NumberFormatException, including a GIF of the error...

Answer (score 1):

Before you parse the double value in ExchangeRateFrom.getText(), print the value and verify if it contains only numbers.
For example use below code to find if the value is correctly entered by user.
Once confirmed you can parse it otherwise convert the string to numeric format and then parse it.

```
try {//put all the logic inside the try catch block
    double ConvertFromGBP = Double.parseDouble(InputFrom.getText());
    double GetExchange = Double.parseDouble(ExchangeRateFrom.getText());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe){//log or print the values and make sure they are numeric
    System.out.println(InputFrom.getText());
    System.out.println(ExchangeRateFrom.getText());
//correct the value (remove special chars and try parsing again)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the parse before you do the checking, so when the program runs, it will crash in the 6th or 7th line depending on which field is empty, and will not reach the check. Put the parsing at the end of the program to ensure you actually check whether the input field is empty or not.